# Show data bound bs modal window to angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angular so this is I am sure a basic question.

I want to use an ng-repeat to render some html and also need a button within the repeated item to show a bs modal window displaying full details about the selected item.

lets say my modal window is very basic like

```
<div id="bs-modal-create" class="modal" ng-model="detail">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3 class="semibold modal-title text-primary"Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" id="wizard">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Title">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="Title" name="Title" placeholder="" type="text" value="" ng-model="title">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My ng-repeat is set up like

```
  <li class="wrapper" data-ng-repeat="detail in vm.details">
      {{detail.name}} <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="someModalWindow()">See full details</a>
  </li>
```

Do I need to include my modal html within the ng-repeat or can it be added just once to my view. How do I tell the modal about the selected item from the ng-repeat?

Again sorry if this is basic stuff, I just can't get my head around it with a bootstrap modal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) instead of the jQuery version (if you already are, go ahead and ignore this line).

Then...

> Do I need to include my modal html within the ng-repeat or can it be added just once to my view

No, you can define it one time as a template and then it will get it's own `$scope`

> How do I tell the modal about the selected item from the ng-repeat?

Your `ng-repeat` items `ng-click` would look like this: `ng-click="someModalWindow(detail)"`

And then inside of your controller, you'd have something like:

```
$scope.someModalWindow = function(detailItem) {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modalTemplate',
      controller: ModalController,
      resolve: {
         detailItem: function () {
            return detailItem;
         }
      }
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function (detailItem) {
    // this is returned from the `$scope.ok` function in ModalController
  }, function () {
    console.log('dismissed');
  });
}
```

You'll also need to define `ModalController`

```
var ModalController = function ($scope, $modalInstance, detailItem) {
  $scope.detailItem = detailItem;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.detailItem); // If you want to return something back to the caller
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

And, finally, your markup:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalTemplate">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{detailItem}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! that was actually quite straight forward with your example